# Redirecting visitors to an Under Construction page for few urls of the website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect visitors(few ips can still have access which belongs to us) on few specific urls of my web site to Under Construction page.

I have used following code to do the complete site redirect to Under Construction page, but this time I need to redirect only a few urls.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^50\.40\.30\.20
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^100\.90\.80\.70
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

let say I need to redirect `/example1/` & `/example2/` pages to Under Construction page. How should I do that with `.htaccess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^50\.40\.30\.20
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^100\.90\.80\.70
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(example1|example2) /maintenance.html [R=302,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^50\.40\.30\.20
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^100\.90\.80\.70
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule (example1|example2) /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

You can exclude multiple pages by using the pipe char **|** .